# Proof that $P(X\geq 2^{-n})\leq 2^nE X$

Tags: probability, expected-value

I saw a statement that $P(X\geq 2^{-n})\leq 2^nE X$ is true (for non-negative random variables X) in this question's answer: [Supermartingale with constant Expectation is a martingale](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177471/supermartingale-with-constant-expectation-is-a-martingale?rq=1) but I am unsure of how this was reached.

I tried writing the probability as an expectation using the indicator function and then as an integral, but then the resulting integral compared to $2^nEX$ doesn't have a clear relationship that I can see.

So I have $\int_{2^-n}^{\infty}dp(X)$ vs. $\int_{0}^{\infty}2^nXdp(X)$, but am unsure how to proceed from there or if that is even the correct way to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: This is actually very similar to the duplicate marked question ([Markov's inequality question about random variable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349839/markovs-inequality-question-about-random-variable)), but I think it's worth leaving up since the duplicate question has the equations as a picture and therefore the search won't find it unless you indicate Markov's inequality, which other users (like I didn't) might not know about!

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The linked question doesn't have the substitution of $a$ to $2^n$ from the normal Markov's inequality. Furthermore, the linked question is the opposite -- it asks for cases where Markov's inequality fails, not cases where it holds.

Comment: Edit: This is actually very similar to the duplicate marked question (Markov's inequality question about random variable.), but I think it's worth leaving up since the duplicate question has the equations as a picture and therefore the search won't find it unless you indicate Markov's inequality, which other users (like I didn't) might not know about!

Comment: @Slade Yeah, you already posted that in the question, no need to repeat it as a comment, especially since the picture thing is not true anymore.

Comment: Well it was just changed (by you) and I don't constantly check the page so I was unaware it was changed. I was posting that as a comment so the argument about whether it was a duplicate could be resolved. I'll delete the question now though.

Comment: Looks like I can't delete it, since it is saying that others have invested time in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from Markov's inequality 
$$\mathbb{P}(X \geq a) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(X)}{a},$$ substituting $2^{-n}$ for $a$.

The wikipedia article gives a proof of Markov's inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality).

Comment: Okay this makes a lot of sense! Thanks!